# Updating a single item inside array inside object Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I have a state like this:

```
const initialState = {
  currentFilters: {
    cities: ["Berlin", "Tokyo", "Madrid"],
  },
};
```

And I want to change a single item inside cities array, so I tried something like this below but it doesn't work correctly:

```
    case "SET_IN_CITIES_ARRAY":
      return {
        ...state,
        currentFilters: {
          ...state.currentFilters,
          cities: [
            state.currentFilters.cities.filter((c, i) =>
              i === action.payload.index ? action.payload.id : c
            ),
          ],
        },
      };
```

action.payload.id can be f.e "Warsaw" and action.payload.index is the item in array that I want to update.

For example:
action.payload.id = "Warsaw"
action.payload.index = 1

should change the cities array to: ["Berlin", "Warsaw", "Madrid"]

Comment: You may want to change `.filter` to `.map` and re-try.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work still

Comment: Just remove the brackets. So it would become `cities: state.currentFilters.cities.map ...`